# SQL select closest row to full hour

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my SQL Server 2012 table (no fixed intervall for inserting):

```
DateTime                    Value
2016-12-16 15:08:03.0740000 17,11233139
2016-12-16 15:08:02.0560000 17,8571434
2016-12-16 15:08:00.0410000 17,11233139
2016-12-16 15:07:58.6570000 17,93345451
2016-12-16 15:07:54.9970000 17,11538506
2016-12-16 15:07:53.5910000 17,93345451
2016-12-16 15:06:45.3220000 17,93650818
2016-12-16 15:06:44.1230000 18,65079308
2016-12-16 15:01:09.0470000 20,41208839
2016-12-16 15:01:05.4060000 19,58791161
2016-12-16 15:01:03.3970000 20,41208839
2016-12-16 15:01:00.4070000 19,73138046
2016-12-16 15:00:57.2230000 20,41208839
2016-12-16 15:00:21.0380000 20,51892471
2016-12-16 15:00:19.0270000 21,22100067
2016-12-16 14:42:45.1810000 20,40903473
2016-12-16 14:27:40.0050000 19,59401703
2016-12-16 14:20:40.2510000 18,65995026
2016-12-16 14:19:03.7750000 18,65995026
2016-12-16 14:01:55.0120000 17,93955994
2016-12-16 13:59:07.9490000 17,12454224
2016-12-16 13:59:06.1180000 16,39499474
```

I would like to have only one row for each hour with the nearest time to the full hour. E.g. for hour 14 this are the closest values to the full hour:

```
2016-12-16 14:01:55.0120000 17,93955994
2016-12-16 13:59:07.9490000 17,12454224
```

The difference to 14:00:00 is smaller for row 2 (53 seconds) so this row should be taken.

How could I do this? Thanks

Comment: What does "for each hour" mean? There are 24 hours in the day. So for each hour you want the closest record? Even if there is a big gap? With your data given the closest record to 7 pm would be the `15:08:03` record. Do you want it this way or only certain hours?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `min` window function.

```
select datetimecol,value 
from (
select t.*,min(datetimecol) over(partition by cast(datetimecol as date),datepart(hour,datetimecol)) mintmstmp
from tablename t
) x
where datetimecol=mintmstmp
```

Edit 1: To get the closest value to a specific hour on a given day, use

```
select top 1 datetimecol,val 
from (select t.*,
      abs(datediff(second,'2016-12-16 14:00:00.0000000',datetimecol)) df
      from tablename t
      ) x
order by df
```

Edit 2: One option would be to generate all the hours of a given day with a recursive cte and join it to the existing table to get the closest timestamp based on time difference.

```
with datetimes as (select cast('2016-12-16 00:00:00.0000000' as datetime2) dt
                   union all
                   select dateadd(hour,1,dt) from datetimes where dt < '2016-12-17 00:00:00.0000000')
select datetimecol,val,dt closest_to_hour
from (
select t.*,dt,
row_number() over(partition by dt order by abs(datediff(second,d.dt,datetimecol))) rn
from tablename t 
join datetimes d on datepart(hour,d.dt) between datepart(hour,datetimecol) and datepart(hour,datetimecol)+1
and cast(d.dt as date) = cast(t.datetimecol as date)
--change this join condition per your specifications
) x
where rn = 1
```

**[`Sample Demo`](http://rextester.com/EZV2383)**

Comment: Shouldnt the fields on the partition be in the reverse order?

Comment: This only takes the Minimum of the full hour. But What if the Date of the previous hour is closer? Like in the example of OP.

Comment: Won't that only grab the times in the same hour? e.g. for 14.00 will pick 14.05 but miss 13.57

Comment: Your second answer only returns one row.

Comment: "I would like to have only one row _for each hour_ with the nearest time to the full hour" so it's needed for multiple hours. It just happens the example data is for a single hour.

Comment: if you read the answer closer, i mentioned it works for a specific hour.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH CTE_ClosestToTheHour AS (

SELECT DateTime, Value,

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATEADD(HH, 
                                DATEPART(HH, DateTime),
                                    CAST(CAST(DateTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
                                    )

                    ORDER BY 
                            ABS(
                            DATEDIFF(ms, DateTime, 

                                DATEADD(HH, 
                                DATEPART(HH, DateTime),
                                    CAST(CAST(DateTime AS DATE) AS DATETIME)
                                    )
                                    )
                                    )
                            ASC
                    ) AS RN

FROM table
)

SELECT * 
FROM CTE_ClosestToTheHour
WHERE RN = 1
ORDER BY DateTime
```

Comment: this gives you the same result as my answer.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: i suggest you verify it instead of downvoting answers hastily.

Comment: Well your first answer's wrong and your second only works for a single hour of a single day. Get it right & I'll upvote.

Comment: @GarethLyons Thanks but it gives me an error `Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.` I think there is the `)` missing for `WITH CTE_ClosestToTheHour AS (`

Comment: @katz thanks, yeah a missing bracket, have edited the code.

Comment: @GarethLyons Thanks, works and gives me the values for the last two hours

Answer (score 0):

This makes use of the`DATEADD` to add 30 minutes to the date then truncating to the nearest hour. The `ROW_NUMBER` function is used to Partition on this date, ordering by the difference between this and the actual datetime and then choosing only the first row for each partition:

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT dt, val,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
             (PARTITION BY dateadd(hour, 
                   datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(mi, 30, dt)), 0) 
             ORDER BY 
                ABS(DateDiff(ms, dt,dateadd(hour, 
                  datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(mi, 30, dt)), 0)))) AS RN
    FROM #T
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE RN=1
```

Comment: thanks but this returns me only the nearest value for the current hour, not for the past